# Convert Captured Image to base64 in React-Native(Expo)

Tags: react-native, base64, expo

I am new to React-Native(Expo). I want to take Image Capture, convert it to base64 and save it to state.

My code is like this:

```
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera  style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  Camera.takePictureAsync({
                    base64: true,
                  }).then(data => {
                          this.setState({base64:data.base64})
                          });
                }}>
                <Text  style={{color: 'white' }}>
                  Capture
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
```

It says takePictureAsync() is not a function. Screenshot of my error is:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about what is the problem? How can I Capture Image and save its base64  to state?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a ref to the Camera object, you need to create an instance of Camera and then trigger it from your app, according to [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera).

Your code should look like this:

```
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera  style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                ref={ref => { this.camera = ref}}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.camera.takePictureAsync({
                    base64: true,
                  }).then(data => {
                          this.setState({base64:data.base64})
                          });
                }}>
                <Text  style={{color: 'white' }}>
                  Capture
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
```

There are two ways to access an inner function. One, instance-level, like you want, another, static level.

**Instance**
You need to call the function on the return from React.render.

**Static**
Take a look at [ReactJS Statics](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#statics). Note, however, that a static function cannot access instance-level data, so this would be undefined.

Comment: I have imported camera and Permissions. I think I have problem with takePictureAsync() function. You can view my complete code here: https://github.com/deependra97/expo.git

Comment: I see, are you managing to use other libraries of Expo? This is very weird as it seems you followed the expo documentation correctly.

Comment: OH! I see, sorry that it took me so long, you're missing this:
`ref={ref => { this.camera = ref}}` and then `this.camera.takePictureAsync`

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Now the function onPress() is working but i still cannot save the base64 of captured image in the state. my onPress() method is like this: 

onPress={() => {
                  this.camera.takePictureAsync({
                    base64: true,
                  }).then(data => {
                          this.setState({base64:data.base64})
                          });
                  console.log(this.state.base64)
                }}